# MONGO DB - PHP. Query in multiple nested data field

Tags: php, mongodb

here expample of my data:

```
 '_id' => new MongoId("54087e076c03943c3c8b456b"),
        'fornitureFuture' => 
      array (
        '0' => 
        array (
          'data_start'▼ => new MongoDate(1412114400, 0),
          'data_end' => new MongoDate(1414710000, 0),
          'f1' => '65',
          'f2' => new MongoInt32(0),
          'f3' => '45',
          'fornitore' => new MongoId("5346cb2ab9d6f0021e6b18a0"),
        ),
        '1' => 
        array (
          'data_start' => new MongoDate(1420066800, 0),
          'data_end' => new MongoDate(1427752800, 0),
          'f1' => '63.75',
          'f2' => new MongoInt32(0),
          'f3' => '70.4',
          'fornitore' => new MongoId("533406896c0394a62c8b4569"),
        ),
```

i need to find if exist a data in fornitureFuture with my MongoDate between data_start and data_end ...

first group  data_start is  10/01/2014 and data_end 10/31/2014
Second group  data_start is 01/01/2015 and data_end 03/31/2015

Something like:

```
//today is 09/19/2014 

$dataTest = mktime(0,0,0,date('n')+2,14,date('Y'));   //return 11/14/2014

$testMese = $this->db->getOne('MyCollection', array('_id'=> new \MongoId($thisPodPdr['_id']), 'fornitureFuture.data_start'=>array('$lte'=> new \MongoDate($dataTest)) , 'fornitureFuture.data_end'=>array('$gt'=> new \MongoDate($dataTest))   ) , array('fornitureFuture'=>1) );
```

I expect empty response but return the record..

2 example:

```
$dataTest = mktime(0,0,0,date('n')+7,14,date('Y'));   //return 04/14/2015

$testMese = $this->db->getOne('MyCollection', array('_id'=> new \MongoId($thisPodPdr['_id']), 'fornitureFuture.data_start'=>array('$lte'=> new \MongoDate($dataTest)) , 'fornitureFuture.data_end'=>array('$gt'=> new \MongoDate($dataTest))   ) , array('fornitureFuture'=>1) );
```

return correctly empty!

I need to test in the same block ...something like

```
'fornitureFuture.$.data_start'=>array('$lte'=> new \MongoDate($dataTest)) , 'fornitureFuture.$.data_end'=>array('$gt'=> new \MongoDate($dataTest))
```

but dont work .

the \ is from namespace  and this->db->getOne(collection,$query,$fields) is my function like $this->collection->findOne($query,$fields);

No syntax error.

sorry for my english and thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Your first example, which returns 2 results when you expect none, runs the following query:

```
[
  '_id' => new MongoId(...),
  'fornitureFuture.data_start' => ['$lte' => new MongoDate(1418533200)],
  'fornitureFuture.data_end' => ['$gt' => new MongoDate(1418533200)],
]
```

The example document you provided has two array elements, with the following date ranges:

1. `1412114400` to `1414710000`
2. `1420066800` to `1427752800`

This document matches because `1412114400` (of the first element) is less than `1418533200`, and `1427752800` (of the second element) is greater than `1418533200`. By simply referring to `fornitureFuture.data_start` and `fornitureFuture.data_end`, MongoDB's query matcher will be satisfied if any array element's sub-field meets the criteria.

You likely want to restrict start/end criteria to same array element, in which case [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) is what you're looking for:

```
[
  '_id' => new MongoId(...),
  'fornitureFuture' => [
    '$elemMatch' => [
        'data_start' => ['$lte' => new MongoDate(1418533200)],
        'data_end' => ['$gt' => new MongoDate(1418533200)],
    ],
  ],
]
```

This criteria should now match only when the start/end dates of the *same element* satisfy the range. On a related note, you may also be interested in the [`$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#array-field-limitations) projection operator, to limit `fornitureFuture` to only the matched element(s).